# OTA Distribution for iOS — no effect with iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ota

Hi.

I have a little problem with OTA Distribution of the iOS. In fact, it totally works with iOS 5 and more, but when I tried on an iOS 4 device, nothing happen. And when I say nothing, it's not a way to say "it doesn't work". No popup, no error message (or even warning message)... But I'm sure I read that OTA Distribution with plist/ipa files works fine in iOS 4.

I use this link :

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://169.254.38.148/Project/DL/dl-6+Testing-98+.html">Testing-98</a>
```

Once again, it works on iOS 5 so... : (

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [BetaBuilder for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/betabuilder-for-ios-apps/id415348946?mt=12)? It works like a charm with iOS 4 and up. Made my life a lot easier!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use this app. And my weird problem is still here... But I think it's a server problem. Like MIME Type or something like this. But I search, make what I've found and it still doesn't work : (

Comment: Sorry that that did not help you. Good luck finding a solution!